# Read Powershell cmdlet argument from a local file

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell Cmdlet where I pass certain arguments as "token" and "days" and it gives me value as below. the values are list of Ids and a token. I would like first the token parameter to be taken from a local text file and next time when we run this it store the generated output token in the same file overwriting it.

So that next time when I run this it take the token which was generated in the last run. How can I do that?

Powershell Cmdlet:

```
Get-ChangedBills -ContinuationToken '18883' -MaxAge '2'
```

Output:

```
ContinuationToken BillsId
----------------- ----------
"184505"          {23, 33, 12, 449...}
```

I would like to store this Continuation Token in a file locally and in next run the Continuation token argument value is taken in the PowerShell cmdlet from the same file.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can use either the `*-CliXml` cmdlets to export &  import the value, OR use a JSON file, OR use a CSV file, OR use a plain text file. [*grin*]

Comment: Well I am aware of that, I am more asking on how to read and store those value in my current cmdlet. Can you please provide the script for reading it from Json or Csv and storing it in there

Comment: you use `Export-CSV` and `Import-CSV` to save/reload data using a CSV file. ///// you use `ConvertTo-Json` and Set-Content` to save JSON to a file & reverse that to load it. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the continuation token value in a simple text file:

```
'18883' |Set-Content .\token.txt
```

Then, in the script that executes `Get-ChangedBills`:

```
param(
  $TokenFilePath = '.\token.txt'
)

$existingToken = Get-Content -Path $TokenFilePath

$changedBills = Get-ChangedBills -ContinuationToken $existingToken -MaxAge '2'

# do your work here

# update token on disk
$changedBills.ContinuationToken.Trim('"') |Set-Content -Path $TokenFilePath
```